# How to configure cmake to get an executable not by default

Tags: cmake

I have a small project with cmake. I build a lib and an executable. on the development machine I want also an executable that cannot be build on other machines/environments.

e.g.:

```
<my-lib>
 | -- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 + -- src/             -> build the lib/archive
 |     |-- lib.c
 |     |-- lib.h
 |     |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 + -- tool             -> build the tool
 |     |-- tool.c
 |     |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 + -- tests            -> build the unit tests
 |     |-- tests.c
 |     |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

I added `CMakeLists.txt` to all directories. Also an `add_executable` to the tests. Now the unit-test executable is build by default. But I want to exclude it from default target.

`CMakeLists.txt` in `tests`:

```
find_library (CUNIT_LIB cunit)
include_directories (${Cunit_INCLUDE_DIRS} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O2 -Wall -Werror")

add_executable (unit-test tests.c)

target_link_libraries (unit-test my-lib cunit)
```

Has anyone a hint how to handle this? I don't want to build unit-test always!

Comment: Do not use `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` for include. If somebody add your project as subdirectory it will has value that you don't expect. It's better to use explicit name `<name>_SOURCE_DIR` or [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR)

Comment: `set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O2 -Wall -Werror")` if user want to define custom compiler flags it will be lost. To fix this use: `set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O2 -Wall -Werror")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple: protect creation of executable by introducing an option/variable.

```
if (DEFINED WITH_UNIT_TEST)
  find_library (CUNIT_LIB cunit)
  include_directories (${Cunit_INCLUDE_DIRS} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

  set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O2 -Wall -Werror")

  add_executable (unit-test tests.c)

  target_link_libraries (unit-test my-lib cunit)
endif ()
```

Now when invoking CMake, one would have to explicitly specify `-DWITH_UNIT_TEST`, so that `unit-test` target is built, while by default it will never be build. For alternative approach, see comments.

Comment: And for those GUI aficionados out there: Consider adding an [option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:option) as well for convenient switching without having to remember the exact command line switch.

Comment: I added the `option (WITH_UNIT_TEST "enable building unit test executable" OFF)` as observed to the toplevel CMakeLists.txt. In that case I have to change the check `if (DEFINED WITH_UNIT_TEST)` to `if (WITH_UNIT_TEST)` because the value is always defined and intialized with `OFF`.

Comment: Yes, sure, if you go with `option` as suggested by @ComicSansMS, then you'd have to check it without `DEFINED`, nevertheless the logic of the solution is absolutely the same.

Comment: Also you can do `add_executable (unit-test EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL tests.c)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a property [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) for such task.

You can write:

```
set_target_properties(unit-test PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
```