# CMake: avoid building tests by default

Tags: cmake

I have `./CMakeLists.txt` and `./test/CMakeLists.txt` is added with `add_subdirectory(test)` command in `./CMakeLists.txt`. Unfortunately, **CMake** builds tests everytime I want to build just main by `make`. Is there a way to avoid building tests in the default target and build tests **only** when I type `make tests`?

Condition

```
if( TARGET tests )
    enable_testing()
endif()
```

in `./test/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't help.

`./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project( my_project VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable( my_project cpp/main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( my_project common )

add_library( common cpp/my_source.hpp )
set_target_properties( common PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX )

project(TEST)
add_subdirectory(test)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

`./test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Add catch as an interface library
set( CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR ../lib/Catch2 )
add_library( Catch INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( Catch INTERFACE ${CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR} )

add_executable( tests test.cpp )
target_link_libraries( tests PUBLIC Catch )

if( TARGET tests )
    enable_testing()
endif()

add_test( NAME tests COMMAND tests )

include(CTest)
# catch_discover_tests(tests)
```

Comment: "avoid building tests in the default target" - What do you mean by building tests? Test executables, created with `add_executable`? Or do you want to not create `tests` target?

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for comment! Yes, **CMake** builds test executable by building `test` target. I want tests target to be created, but build it only when I explicitly type `make tests`, **not** when I type `make`.

Comment: "CMake builds test executable by building test target." - No, this is wrong. CMake builds a test executable because it is defined with `add_executable`. By default, all such targets are build with `all`(default) target. You may redefine this behavior by adding `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` flag for `add_executable` call. This flag could also be passed to `add_subdirectory`, so it will affect on all libraries/executables defined in the subdirectory. From the other side, `test` target has no dependencies. So if you want to build something before testing, you need to create another target with dependency.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Replacing `add_subdirectory( test )` with `add_subdirectory( test EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL )` solved the issue! Thank you very much! Should I format it up as the solution?

Comment: Actually, this topic is not a new one, and I have found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500118/how-to-configure-cmake-to-get-an-executable-not-by-default/50874088) with similar problem as yours. As for dependencies from `test` and test executables, there are also several questions on Stack Overflow. See e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733475/cmake-ctest-make-test-doesnt-build-tests).

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah I've seen that one, but problem there is opposite to mine: I couldn't get rid of **tests** being built.

Comment: Em, How your "Is there a way to avoid building tests in the default target" differs from "I don't want to build unit-test always!" in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20500118/3440745)? And its [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874088/3440745) suggests using exactly `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it's title is **How to configure cmake to get an executable not by default** - maybe topic is dug somewhere deeper into the question which over-complicates googling. It's OK though it might be a duplicate indeed.

Comment: While I could find some similarity between the title - **How to configure cmake to get an executable not by default** - and the problem "I don't want to build unit-test always!", - I agree, that the title is not so good. Unfortunately, I cannot suggest another title, since I understand the question only partially. Actually, I feel the same about your question, but similarity of code and solution makes me to think about "duplicate".